# Removing certain objects from array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I want to do is to remove a set of objects from my original array of objects in angularjs.

I have this set of array of objects:

```
var obj = [{
id: 1,
name: "Ben",
role: [{
    roleId: 1,
    roleName: role01
},
{
    roleId: 2,
    roleName: role02
}]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Anna",
    role: [{
        roleId: 3,
        roleName: role03
    },
    {
        roleId: 4,
        roleName: role04
    }]
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Dan",
    role: [{
        roleId: 3,
        roleName: role03
    },
    {
        roleId: 4,
        roleName: role04
    }]
},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "Matt",
    role: [{
        roleId: 1,
        roleName: role01
    },
    {
    roleId: 2,
    roleName: role02
    }]
}];
```

And I want to remove these elements from the array above:

```
var removeObj = [{
    id: 3,
    name: "Dan",
    role: [{
        roleId: 3,
        roleName: role03
    },
    {
        roleId: 4,
        roleName: role04
    }]
},
{
    id: 4,
    name: "Matt",
    role: [{
        roleId: 1,
        roleName: role01
    },
    {
    roleId: 2,
    roleName: role02
    }]
}];
```

Is this solution possible?

P.S. What I have done is to use 'splice' but it only removes one element at a time. Can splice also removes a set of elements inside an object?

```
obj.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: perhaps the fact you are using the term `JSON object` made it difficult for you to search for an answer for yourself. Hint: there is no such thing as a `JSON object` - except for the global JSON object that has methods `stringify` and `parse` to create and parse JSON respectively

Comment: There is no JSON shown in the question, and [there ain't no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/): you have an array of objects. I've edited the question to remove references to JSON. `.splice()` can remove multiple adjacent elements at once. To remove elements based on whether they match some condition try `.filter()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Solution 1 using filter
let removeArray = removeObj.map(function(item){
  return item.id;
});
let result1 = obj.filter(function(item){
  return !removeArray.includes(item.id);
});
console.log(result1);

//Solution 2 using slice
//Considered it's valid just if obj is ordered by id and removeObj too.
let result2 = obj.slice(0,removeObj.length);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Solution 1 looks good, but Solution 2 doesn't answer the question because it doesn't use `removeObj` at all. If you replaced Solution 2 with an explanation of Solution 1 I'd vote for this.

Comment: Will be trying your solution later. Will accept this answer if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider usage of 3rd party library to simplify that, I will recommend you lodash: https://lodash.com.

It provides serious amount of methods to work with collections. This is the one you need in your case. Simply do `_.difference(obj, removeObj)` and let the library do everything for you.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference